# Magento 2 : How to overwrite file Magento Review controller

Tags: magento2, product, product-review

My requirement is to send an email to admin when a customer adds a product review. For that, I want to overwrite controller Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post.php

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also rewrite functinality with plugin

**1.Create di.xml file at Vendor/Module/etc and add below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Vendor_Plugin_Magento_Review_Controller_Product_Post" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2.Create Post.php file at  Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Review/Controller/Product and add below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Review\Controller\Product;

class Post
{

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //Your custom code to send email to customer.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **Namespace\Module\etc\di.xml** and add the code below.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post" type="Namespace\Module\Controller\Product\Post" />
</config>
```

create **Namespace\Module\Controller\Product\Post.php**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Review\Controller\Product as ProductController;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;

class Post extends \Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post
 {
        public function execute()
        {
           $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                return $resultRedirect;
            }

            $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
            if ($data) {
                $rating = [];
                if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                    $rating = $data['ratings'];
                }
            } else {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
                $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
            }

            if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
                /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
                $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);

                $validate = $review->validate();
                if ($validate === true) {
                    try {
                        $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                            ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                            ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                            ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                            ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                            ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                            ->save();

                        foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                            $this->ratingFactory->create()
                                ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                                ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                                ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                        }

                        $review->aggregate();
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You submitted your review for moderation.Thanks'));
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    if (is_array($validate)) {
                        foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                            $this->messageManager->addError($errorMessage);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                    }
                }
            }
            $redirectUrl = $this->reviewSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl ?: $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.
This is working code for review controller override in magento 2. Thanks.